# Spark Write all related data into a single file

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have challenge, I am not sure how to do it in Spark Scala Dataframe.

I have a dataframe, amongst many columns, 2 key columns are brand(3) and customerId(~700K).

When I write this df and partitionBy(brand), I get 3 folders, 1 for each brand, and about 200 files in each folder. Each file may contain data for many customerId and data for each customerId may be scattered across different files.

**The challenge is to partitionBy(brand), but need to ensure data for a single customerId is fully contained in a single file. It's ok if a file contains data for multiple customerId, but the data should be complete within that file.**

I can partitionBy(brand, customerId) but that will create 3 top level folders and then 700K folders underneath that, I don't want that, that's unmanageable.

**I need 3 folders and about 100 files within each folder, but data for a given customerId is fully contained in a single file but a single file can contain data fully for multiple customerIds**

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It might be easier done as a post processing outside of Spark.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add a logical column based on customerId: new_col
such as customerId = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
you can generate new_col = (1,1,1,2,2,2)

aggregate new_col the aggregated data as a whole for the same data,
so that you can aggregate data with the same or similar customerId.
 
Reduce the number of files in each folder using coalesce(100)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have gone with this approach in the end. Although not elegant but it works!